# Displaying Text from Javascript function output

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function which outputs text in seconds. However, I am struggling trying to display that output on my HTML page. The function is:

```
hypeDocument.currentTimeInTimelineNamed(timelineName)
```

I have tried many solutions but have gotten nowhere. My latest attempt to display the seconds was:

```
var countDownTimer = function (text) {
    hypeDocument.currentTimeInTimelineNamed('timerTenSeconds');
};
```

I don't know where to go from here. Can anyone help me please understand this?

Cheers, Ash

Comment: Show what your function does(its content).

Comment: what is the hypeDocument object? And the hypeDocument.currentTimeInTimelineNamed method???

Comment: Ok guys, I am unable to show the function output as I can get it to work but it's a build in API in the program itself. To quote the documentation: **"API Functions

Tumult Hype offers many JavaScript APIs to control various aspects of a document. These APIs can be called both by JavaScript functions written within Tumult Hype, and by scripts external to the document."** and also another quote but specific to the API: *** "hypeDocument.currentTimeInTimelineNamed('timelineName')

Returns the current time of the specified timeline in seconds."***

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  Documentation for the script and API is (http://tumult.com/hype/documentation/3.0/#api-functions)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your html looks like but if you just want to display your output on the page try:

```
document.write( myFunction() );
```